# dig does not resolve unqualified domain names, but nslookup does

Tags: bind, dig, nslookup

I have a lab set up with DNS running on a CentOS7 server (`dns01.local.lab`). The `local.lab` domain is defined in `named.conf`:

```
zone "local.lab" IN {
    type master;
    file "local.lab.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

I also have a reverse zone but that doesn't matter for this question as far as I can tell.

The zone file looks like:

```
$TTL 86400
@  IN SOA  dns01.local.lab. root.local.lab. (
    1 ; Serial
    3600 ; Refresh
    1800 ; Retry
    604800 ; Expire
    86400 ; Minimum TTL
)
@        IN NS  dns01.local.lab.
@        IN A   192.168.122.100
@        IN A   192.168.122.1
dns01      IN A 192.168.122.100
virt-host  IN A 192.168.122.1
```

If I use `nslookup` using just the hostname I get a resolved IP:

```
[root@dns01 ~]# nslookup dns01
Server:          192.168.122.100
Address:         192.168.122.100#53

Name:    dns01.local.lab
Address:  192.168.122.100
```

However, if I use `dig` using just the hostname I do not get the expected response:

```
[root@dns01 ~]# dig dns01

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.2 <<>> dns01
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 9070
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER 0; AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dns01.                         IN        A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       10800   IN        SOA    a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2016020401 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 95 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.122.100#53(192.168.122.100)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 04 09:15:07 HST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109
```

I only get the expected response when I use the FQDN:

```
[root@dns01 ~]# dig dns01.local.lab

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.2 <<>> dns01
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 9070
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER 1; AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dns01.local.lab.               IN        A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dns01.local.lab.        86400   IN        A        192.168.122.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
local.lab.              86400   IN        NS       dns01.local.lab.

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.122.100#53(192.168.122.100)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 04 09:22:15 HST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 74
```

Reverse lookups with `dig` provide the expected answer. Likewise with `nslookup`.

I know that `dig` and `nslookup` use different resolver libraries, but from what I understand `dig` is considered the *better* way.

As the results above indicate, the correct named server is being queried. It's as if `dig` doesn't recognize that the server is the authority for hostname being queried.

`named.conf`:

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.122.100; };
    directory    "/var/named";
    dump-file    "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file    "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file    "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query    {localhost; 192.168.122.0/24; };
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

zone "local.lab" IN {
    type master;
    file "local.lab.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "122.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "local.lab.revzone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does `dig +search dns01` give you what you want? If so, it it possible that `+nosearch` somehow got added to your `~/.digrc` ?

ETA: Or, if you're like me, maybe the dig fairies failed to come and add `+search` to your `~/.digrc`.

Comment: Adding `+search` to `.digrc` (which didn't already exist) fixed it. That's a bit of a nuisance. I would think `dig` would be smart enough to search the domain when `nslookup` is.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nuisance, but now that you know, you can just add it to `~/.digrc` and forget about it.

Comment: Isn't `+nosearch` the default anyway (the search list is not used  _by default_) ? I thought it was the reason I pretty much always use the combination `dig +search ...` on Ubuntu boxes running 14.04 and 15.10. -- just curious ---

Comment: @Cbhihe Looks like that's what the OP is seeing, yes.

Comment: I have the same problem and in my system there is no .digrc file, does anybody know how to solve this problem without editing this file?

Comment: @Volex Why not just create `.digrc`? Or, if for some reason you absolutely can't create it, just pass the arguments you want on the command line.

Comment: @arensb dig, even with +search, doesn't work for me. only FQDNs work